# Could the attractive force of gravity be modeled as a repulsive force?

Tags: gravity

If space intrinsically contained gravitons of many different wavelengths then could gravity be model as a repulsive force simular to how casimir attraction works?  or any other repulsive mechanism you can think of.

Comment: Look in the side bar. See http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/21720/ and http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/26692/ If this question differs in any important way from them you should probably make that clear.

Comment: That helps answering the "any other" question. I'm interested in the exclusion of various wavelengths that can't form between objects and how large round objects compare to 2 flat plates.

Comment: As an attractive force, the square of distance works, as it does in other disciplines.