# What happens if we find out that antimatter particles "fall up"?

Tags: gravity, mass, antimatter

What happens if in [this experiment](https://home.cern/news/news/experiments/new-antimatter-gravity-experiments-begin-cern) we find out that antimatter "repels gravity", i.e., falls away from the earth?
(Probably not gonna happen, our universe would never delight us with such a surprise)

What would be evident about the nature of our universe immediately after this discovery?

Comment: We already know that they don't fall 'up' from previous, albeit 'crude' experiments. These new experiments will narrow the error bars and start to tell us more about how similar regular and anti hydrogen are.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9371/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/476141/2451 and links therein.

Comment: This must be a duplicate so I'm not going to add an answer, but, briefly, if antimatter falls up then General Relativity is a dead theory.

Comment: @JonCuster If you are referring to the Fairbanks experiment that claim has been retracted.

Answer (score 0):

> What happens if in this experiment we find out that antimatter "repels gravity", i.e., falls away from the earth? (Probably not gonna happen, our universe would never delight us with such a surprise)

It would set theorists working on looking through the existing models for a theory of everything, to see which can describe the data.

> What would be evident about the nature of our universe immediately after this discovery?

That a further step in studying nature has been achieved.

See also [this question.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/34493/is-anti-gravity-i-e-repulsive-gravity-possible-in-theoretical-physics)