# Does repulsive or opposite gravitational force exist?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, gravity, newtonian-gravity

According to Newton's third law of motion, every force have an equal and opposite reaction. So, using that law, is there a reaction of gravitational force that acts in the opposite direction and is repulsive?

If you throw a ball towards the ground, it would bounce up to a certain height. This bounce happens in opposite direction and is repulsive, so is it a clue that repulsive gravitational force exists?

Comment: What is the ball bouncing back up supposed to have to do with the gravitational force?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/34493/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/11542/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 4):

> According to Newton's third law of motion, every force have an equal and opposite reaction. So, using that law, is there a reaction of gravitational force that acts in opposite direction and is repulsive?

The third law means that the net force on the system as a whole must be zero.  It does not mean that a repulsive gravitational force is required.  It means that *each* body experiences an attractive force towards the other.  These forces are in opposite directions and of equal magnitude, so the net force is zero.  But from the point of view of either body it is attracting the other body.

> If you throw a ball to a ground, it would bounce up to a certain height. This bounce happens in opposite direction and is repulsive, so is it a clue that repulsive gravitational force exists?

If you throw a ball into a wall or ceiling it also bounces - no gravity involved.  In fact if you do that in zero gravity it still bounces.  Gravity has nothing to do with the bounce.