# Attractiveness of spin 2 gauge theories

Tags: gravity, quantum-gravity, gauge-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is gravitation force always attractive?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/11542/why-is-gravitation-force-always-attractive)

I have heard that the attractiveness of gravitation is due to the fact that it is a spin 2 gauge theory. Why is this so? I find this very interesting and would love to understand this fact.

Comment: The duplicate link I posted contains a link to quite a detailed article on the subject. I can't say how good the article is because I understood not a word of it :-)

Comment: @JohnRennie I see a problem with the answer given there: the charge of gravitation is not a scalar, but the energy momentum tensor.

Comment: [Tony Zee](http://press.princeton.edu/titles/7573.html) gives a nice plausibility argument for this based on the form of the spin 2 propagator, and contrasts this with the spin 1 propagator which results in a repulsive force (if the charges are like)