# Why do like charges repel in a spin-1 gauge theory, while they attract in spin-2 theories?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, yang-mills

A presenter recently said this at a colloquium, but they didnt explain why. I know a fair bit of GR and Yang-Mills theory, so dont shy away from the details (unless they are cumbersome and don't aid in understanding).

Comment: Answered here. https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/78999/66086

Comment: @CosmasZachos Not a good answer. Just a verbal description of a mathematical formula with no physical meaning given. May do for the OP, but meaningless for 99% users here.