# Why do gauge particles with odd spin cause opposite charges to attract, while those with even spin cause them to repel? What's the math behind it?

Tags: forces, quantum-spin, interactions, carrier-particles

I have read that opposite charges attract when mediated by odd-spin gauge particles, like the photon, and that they repel when mediated by even-spin gauge particles, like the graviton.

Is there an intuïtive explanation for this or is it a logical mathematical consequence, and if so, how does it work?

EDIT

In the first answer to [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/78995/) question (why gravity is attractive) we can read:

> In Quantum Field Theory, "forces" between 2 "charged" particles correspond to an exchange of "virtual gauge bosons". For instance, the repulsive force between 2 electrons, corresponds to an "exchange" of a "virtual photon" (a perturbation of the photon field). Here the gauge boson is the photon, of spin 1.

> We may consider a graviton theory as a QFT, in this case, the charge is the momentum/energy of the particle, and the gauge boson is the graviton, of spin 2.

> In these theories, you have to write a Lagrangian, and you have to respect a sign coherence about the Euclidean action which has to be positive. This constraint gives you the correct sign for the Lorentz-invariant Lagrangian.

The mathematical procedure is explained in words, but I'm curious about the actual math involved. I can't find it nowhere. What is the "sign of coherence about the Euclidean action" you have to respect? And how does the correct sign for the Lorentz-invariant Lagrangian ensure that odd/even-spin gauge particles cause like charges to repel/attract?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/458161/2451

Comment: You might find this [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/630239/180269) of mine (and reference therein) helpful.

Comment: @A.V.S. Yes! It's more or less written in your answer! That's what I mean! I can see that the potential energy gets negative because of the (-1)^(s+1)  for even spin, so likes attract, though I'm not sure I completely understand why this is the case. It's a pity I can't access the article you link to.