# Gravitational Force (conceptual)

Tags: gravity, forces, newtonian-gravity

1. Why is gravitational force always an attractive force?
2. And is the [Newtonian formula of gravitational force](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_law_of_universal_gravitation) applicable for very small particles like electrons and protons etc.? 
   From **Formula of Gravitational Force**, I'm referring to: 
   $$F_G = \cfrac{GMm}{R^2}, $$ 
   where $M$ and $m$ are the masses of objects.

A logical explanation will be much appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is gravitation force always attractive?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/11542/)

Comment: I've linked a duplicate to your first question. Re the second question: gravity is universal and affects fundamental partcles and even light rays just as it does big objects.

Comment: I see. Didn't notice that there is a duplicate question too. Sorry! And thanks for the answer of second questin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see ravi

As the formula shows that gravitational force is directly proportional to the masses of both the bodies [consider proton and electron] their masses are way too small [mass of electron is $9.10938291 × 10^{-31}$ kilograms] [mass of proton is $1.67262178 × 10^{-27}$ kilograms] and the radius of the first p-orbital from the nucleus is $5.2917721092(17)×10^{−11}$ m calculation of these all terms will lead to a very small froce of order $10^{-47}$ units which will almost equal to zero so the force is negligible.

so is your doubt clear now? feel free to comment for any further doubts