# Why does mass attract?

Tags: gravity, mass

Question stands as title says:
Do we know (straight probable is reasoning is meant by "knowing") why mass is doing so?

Comment: You may find the following question helpful: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/129987/

Comment: observation of masses inter-attractions is a physical fact. Any theory that doesn't render this fact is not effective

Comment: Sorry I'm not from the scientific field. So if there is something a fact no one is keeping to ask why? (I don't want to make any scientific statements or so. I just was interested about we know why this is.)

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/11542/2451 and links therein.