# gravity, it's positive or negative?

Tags: gravity

what is the direction of gravity, it's positive or negative?

Comment: What do you mean by "direction"?

Comment: You can use any coordinate system you want. The choice of coordinate system will determine the direction (and thus the sign) of any vector quantity.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/11542/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Sigh... voting to close

Comment: The force of gravity, which is a vector quantity, therefore not positive or negative per se, in the sense that in a vector space $V$ one doesn't usually define an [order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set) and therefore if $\mathbf{v}\in V$ it may well make no sense to say that $\mathbf{v}$ is $>0$ or $<0$. What we can say is that the force of gravity exerced **by** a material point $P_1$ of mass $m_1$ **on** another point $P_2$ of mass $m_2$, whose distance is $r$, point **from** $P_2$ **to** $P_1$...

Comment: ...i.e. it's $\frac{Gm_1 m_2}{r^2}\hat{\mathbf{r}}$ where $\hat{\mathbf{r}}$ is a unitary vector pointing from $P_2$ to $P_1$, which is the same as  $-\frac{Gm_1 m_2}{r^2}\hat{\mathbf{u}}$ if $\hat{\mathbf{u}}$ is a unitary vector pointing from $P_1$ to $P_2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> gravity, it's positive or negative?

The most convenient reference systems are the ones having the origin at a point on the surface of the earth or in the center of our planet, work with a negative *acceleration due to gravity* because *g* points to the origin.