# Can curved space also cause repulsion?

Tags: gravity

Usually curved spacetime looks like it causes objects to attract to each other. But is the opposite also possible? For instance if I twist/curve a towel in one direction it is getting smaller but in the other direction it is getting longer (the length of it gets another direction (diagonal or straight). So is it possible that a curveture also creates a repellent effect?

Comment: I've never been able to twist/curve a towel in such a way that it is *longer* than the length of one of its diagonals, unless you take into consideration any stretching/pulling of the towel.  But essentially you're talking about an anti-gravity effect?

Comment: Related: [Why is gravitation force always attractive?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/11542/50583)

Comment: I've read the anwer but why cannot  normal matter create a stress-energy tensor of the required form?