# Has the gravity a negative value?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, mass

We all know that the acceleration of the gravity is equivalent to 9.81 m/s². But the gravity attract everything that have a mass (everything as far as i know) to the center of a planet.

As an magnetic field that attract another magnetic with a opposite pole, is the gravity an negative value to attract the positive masses that have in the planet (specially the earth)?

Comment: If you like this question you may also enjoy reading [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/11542/2451) Phys.SE post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gravity is not “a negative value”. Gravitational force and gravitational accelerations are *vectors* whose direction is attractive. What this means is that, if you have two massive objects, each one experiences a force towards, and accelerates towards, the other one.

Two masses attract even though both masses are positive. (As far as we know, *all* mass is positive.) By contrast, two positive charges repel. To get the vector pointing in the attractive direction, there is a negative sign in the gravitational force equation. But this does not mean there is a negative *value*.

Answer (score 1):

A gravitational force is a vector quantity.  A vector is never negative. It has a positive magnitude and a direction. After you define a coordinate system, a vector can be broken into components, some of which may be negative.

Answer (score 0):

Outside involved masses gravitational energy potential is ~ *-1/r* for distance *r*; in this sense YES. The offset of the absolute energy of a system does not contribute to the laws; regarding this neither YES nor NO.