# Mass and Gravitational Force

Tags: gravity, cosmology, mass, matter

- Why do mass has a tendency to attract other masses and form bigger cluster of mass?
- What cause gravitational force to exist?
- Is it so that at one point of time all matter in universe will form cluster of mass or annihilate?

Comment: *Is it so that at one point of time all matter in universe will form cluster of mass or annihilate?* Current evidence indicates that the opposite of clustering is happening. Galaxies are getting farther and farther from each other, faster and faster. If if for some reason this reverses and matter clumps, there will be no annihilation for the simple reason that there an insignificant amount of antimatter.

Comment: If only energy existed at the time of big bang then matter and antimatter should cancel each other or there must be other thing to stretch space out(if antimatter ain't equal to matter). But, why do gravitational force exist? Is it so that mass should again return to energy?

Comment: Gravitational force exists by virtue of the curvature caused in space-time due to the presence of an object with mass.

Comment: Cosmologists believe that matter and antimatter *already* annihilated in the early universe. There was a slight (one part in a billion or so) excess of matter, and that is what makes up today's universe. Physicists do *not* think that the current universe is 50% antimatter.

Comment: Asking “why is physics like it is?” is generally not a question that physics can currently (or possibly ever) answer. Nature is what it is, and the job of physics is to understand how it works, not why it works that way. If you want to know why, you should ask a philosopher or a theologian (and then be extremely skeptical of their answers).

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/11542/2451 and links therein.