# Gravity between antimater and matter

Tags: gravity

Always considered antimater as negative mass so:
$$m1=10kg(matter)$$
$$m2=-10kg(antimater)$$
$$displacement=r=10m$$
$$gravity =\frac{Gm1m2}{r^2}=-1N<0!HOW?$$

Comment: That is not 0zero factorial.

Comment: What happened to the value of $G$?

Comment: Antimatter doe not have a negative mass. It has the opposite charge.

Comment: Here's a recent question on this topic. Although it's closed, it has good info & links. https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/589812/123208

Comment: Also note that when antimatter annihilates with regular matter it releases positive energy. That's been measured innumerable times.

Comment: Related:https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/230786/what-effects-would-a-finding-of-gravitational-repulsion-between-matter-and-anti

Answer (score 2):

- Physicists mostly expect antimatter to have positive gravitational mass because it has positive inertial mass, but until that's empirically verified it's the subject of a small controversy.
- The sign of a force indicates whether it attracts or repels. (If any inertial mass were negative, you'd have to take that into account as well.
- In fact, Newton's formula for the gravity between two positive gravitational masses reflects its being attractive by having a minus sign you didn't know about, in $-Gm_1m_2\vec{r}/r^2=-Gm_1m_2\hat{r}/r^3$.

Comment: By assuming antimater mass <0 I felt it would repel mater.

Comment: @ask Well, now I've explained how signs work, you needn't ever get confused when doing these calculations.