# Will antimatter fall upward in a gravitational force field?

Tags: electrostatics, gravity, newtonian-gravity, mass, antimatter

A positively charged particle has a force acting along the electric force field. The contrary is true for a negatively charged particle.
Can we apply the same analogy for antimatter and say that antimatter will fall upward in a gravitational force field?
Furthermore the energy of a bound system of two oppositely charged particles is negative implying that energy is released when such a system forms. Similar is seen for matter and antimatter.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/534289/2451 and links therein.

Comment: No it won't.  Remember that gravity is caused by curvature in spacetime, not by a  charge (as per magnetism.)  So anything that is caught in that spacetime curvature is pulled towards the planet.  That even includes light which is bent by this spacetime curvature.   I compare gravity to a low pressure system in the weather, where this low pressure in time (time dilation near a planet) causes things to fall towards the planet, like a low pressure in the weather sucks things towards the centre of the low.  What you are describing would require that a planet cause time contraction (speeding up).

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/230786/